# AWS lambda-function-public-access-prohibited rule in Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In AWS's Config, I set a rule called: "lambda-function-public-access-prohibited".  This says it runs its own lambda to "check", but I can't seem to find much else on what it's doing or how it determines that it's publicly accessible.

Can anyone point me to documentation on this or know what it's doing exactly?

Thank you!

Comment: I was just looking for the same information.  I want to test this config rule and try to replicate it into CloudCustodian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [AWS Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/lambda-function-public-access-prohibited.html)

Under Function policy, if the policy allows actions for the principal element “*” or {“AWS”: “*”}, it is publicly accessible.

Consider adding the following IAM condition to scope access to your account only.

```
"Condition": {
  "StringEquals": {
    "AWS:SourceAccount": "<account_id>"
    }
  }
}
```

source: https://hub.steampipe.io/mods/turbot/aws_compliance/controls/control.pci_v321_lambda_1?context=benchmark.pci_v321/benchmark.pci_v321_lambda

**EDIT: This config rule was triggered by an S3 bucket resource attached to the lambda. In the console's resource-based policy form, you can specify an AWS account number. Once specified this will automatically create the above policy. After rescanning your config rules should appear as resolved.**

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you don't give * in resource or actions, so as to get all resources who have AWS account can access your lambda.

```
{
            "Sid": "lambdaAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
          },
```

- Instead you can give ARN in resources and specific action like read, write, get access in action item.

**Recommended** :

```
{
            "Sid": "lambdaAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "lambda:GetFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws-us:lambda:us-west-1:123456789:function:lambda1234"
          },
```